# How to execute setup method/block only once per feature method?

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I have simple groovy & spock test class written in spring boot, with `setup`,`expect`,`cleanup` and `where` block, but the problem here is the `setup` block is getting executed for each iteration in where block which is not the way i need. so my question is there a way to make `setup()`  method to execute only once before each method

```
import spock.lang.Specification
class SpockSpec extends Specification {

  def setupSpec() { println 'setupSpec()' }

  def setup() { println 'setup()' }

  def cleanup() { println 'cleanup()' }

  def cleanupSpec() { println 'cleanupSpec()' }

  def 'test blocks'() {

     setup:
     println 'setup:'

     expect:
     println "expect: $data"

     cleanup:
     println 'cleanup:'

     where:
     data << [1, 2]
  }
}
```

**Output :**

```
setupSpec()
setup()
setup:
expect: 1
cleanup:
cleanup()
setup()
setup:
expect: 2
cleanup:
cleanup()
cleanupSpec()
```

**Expected Output :**.  //`setup()` method only executed once before method and not for each iteration in where

```
setupSpec()
setup()
setup:
expect: 1
cleanup:
cleanup()
setup:
expect: 2
cleanup:
cleanup()
cleanupSpec()
```

Comment: Why don't you use `setupSpec()`?

Comment: I think your subject "How to execute setup block after all iteration of where block in groovy spock test class" does not reflect what you really want to do. I am going to change it to what I think is correct according to what you describe in your question. Please double-check. Thanks.

Comment: Friendly reminder: Please provide feedback to the people trying to help you. After you will have done so, I shall delete this comment. 

Comment: Hi @kriegaex i completely forgotten about this, but as per your answer i can use `setupSpec` since i want some database clean up code need to execute after each test method

Comment: `setupSpec()` runs **before** the first feature of a specification, not **after** anything. If you want code executed _"after each test method"_ as you said, you need to use the `cleanup()` method. But that contradicts your statements in the question, which is quite confusing. So what shall it be now? Please make up your mind and communicate in a consistent way.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: This is not how Spock works. Both `setup()` and `setup:` are meant to be executed for each iteration of a parametrised test because logically each iteration is an independent feature method. I think it is good like this.

Leonard suggested:

> Why don't you use `setupSpec()`?

`setupSpec()` won't cut it here if there is more than one feature method.

You could write a Spock extension, either global or annotation-driven, which could help you skip `setup()` execution under specific circumstances. I have discussed both variants with Marcin Erdmann, the maintainer of Geb, on the Geb mailing list in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/geb-user/c/zsILBsH-DxE/m/4hqdCTprBgAJ). You could copy the code for the variant you prefer and adjust it to your needs, i.e. instead of always skipping `setup()` whenever a feature method is annotated by a custom `@SkipSetup` annotation, you could extend the annotation to take a closure to be evaluated as a condition or just hard-code skipping all iterations but the first for a hypothetical `@SetupOnce` annotation.

Or you could just refactor your tests to use canonical Spock, e.g. make your setup code only do something if a `@Shared` variable has a certain value. I have not seen your code, but my feeling is that if you think you need this feature, something is wrong with your test design.

---

**Update:** I was thinking about something like this:

**Annotation-driven Spock extension:**

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.testing.extension

import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.ExtensionAnnotation

import java.lang.annotation.Retention
import java.lang.annotation.Target

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
@ExtensionAnnotation(SetupOnceExtension)
@interface SetupOnce {}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.testing.extension

import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractMethodInterceptor
import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.IMethodInvocation

class SetupOnceMethodInterceptor extends AbstractMethodInterceptor {
  Map<String, Boolean> annotatedFeatures = new HashMap<>()

  @Override
  void interceptSetupMethod(IMethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    if (annotatedFeatures.containsKey(invocation.feature.name)) {
      if (!annotatedFeatures[invocation.feature.name]) {
        invocation.proceed()
        annotatedFeatures[invocation.feature.name] = true
      }
    }
    else
      invocation.proceed()
  }
}
```

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.testing.extension

import org.spockframework.runtime.extension.AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension
import org.spockframework.runtime.model.FeatureInfo

class SetupOnceExtension extends AbstractAnnotationDrivenExtension<SetupOnce> {
  SetupOnceMethodInterceptor interceptor

  @Override
  void visitFeatureAnnotation(SetupOnce annotation, FeatureInfo feature) {
    if (!interceptor) {
      interceptor = new SetupOnceMethodInterceptor()
      feature.spec.addSetupInterceptor interceptor
    }
    interceptor.annotatedFeatures[feature.name] = false
  }
}
```

**Sample Spock specification:**

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.testing.extension

import spock.lang.Specification

class SetupOnceTest extends Specification {
  def setup() {
    println "SetupOnceTest -> setup"
  }

  def feature1() {
    setup:
    println "SetupOnceTest -> feature1"
    expect:
    true
  }

  @SetupOnce
  def feature2() {
    setup:
    println "SetupOnceTest -> feature2"
    expect:
    true
  }

  def feature3() {
    setup:
    println "SetupOnceTest -> feature3, iteration $count"
    expect:
    true
    where:
    count << [1, 2, 3]
  }

  @SetupOnce
  def feature4() {
    setup:
    println "SetupOnceTest -> feature4, iteration $count"
    expect:
    true
    where:
    count << [1, 2, 3]
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

As you can see, for `feature4()` the `setup()` method is executed only once. The extension does not affect `setup:` blocks though, they will always be executed.

```
SetupOnceTest -> setup
SetupOnceTest -> feature1
SetupOnceTest -> setup
SetupOnceTest -> feature2
SetupOnceTest -> setup
SetupOnceTest -> feature3, iteration 1
SetupOnceTest -> setup
SetupOnceTest -> feature3, iteration 2
SetupOnceTest -> setup
SetupOnceTest -> feature3, iteration 3
SetupOnceTest -> setup
SetupOnceTest -> feature4, iteration 1
SetupOnceTest -> feature4, iteration 2
SetupOnceTest -> feature4, iteration 3
```

Comment: **Update:** I added a sample extension, sample test and console log.

Comment: `setupSpec() won't cut it here if there is more than one feature method.` while true, you can easily just have a spec with one data driven method. It is the simplest solution to the stated problem. Of course your extension is more powerful, whether it is necessary depends on the rest of the code, that is why I asked the OP to clarify. BTW, it will be necessary to use `@Shared` otherwise the fields initialized by `setup` are null after the first iteration.